# How to find all negative slope straight lines and get the one with the minimum y=0 value

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, line

I would like to implement a function that plots a histogram and compute the minimum `y=0` value of all the negative slope straight lines computed using the coordinates of the bins.

For example, this plot:

```
i1s1=[1.081576, 1.063301000000001, 0.7665449999999989, 0.6702140000000014, 0.9948089999999983, 0.8247, 
      1.0281650000000013, 1.0204430000000002, 0.9952000000000005, 0.8824919999999992, 1.0094080000000005, 
      0.23627600000000015, 0.7032509999999981, 0.34252400000000094, 0.5976010000000009, 0.9419879999999985, 
      1.1269390000000001, 1.0165110000000013, 0.803722999999998, 1.2493930000000013, 0.3798589999999997, 
      0.5761640000000021, 1.0876199999999976, 0.8915590000000009, 0.9461050000000029, 1.0046489999999935, 
      0.8577720000000042, 1.131541999999996, 0.9394370000000052, 1.939746999999997, 0.7513170000000002, 
      0.7799210000000016, 0.2271250000000009, 0.5776759999999967, 1.0690549999999988, 1.2057460000000049, 
      2.6899219999999957, 3.521351000000003, 0.8345109999999991, 1.1897260000000003, 0.9561250000000001, 
      2.113745999999999, 0.7494179999999986, 1.1265460000000047, 0.8125209999999967, 2.5974119999999985, 
      0.7458990000000014, 1.0843160000000012, 0.9465989999999991, 0.8917330000000021, 0.933920999999998, 
      2.2939850000000064, 1.3038799999999924, 1.7666460000000086]
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x=i1s1, bins='auto', color='#0504aa',
                            alpha=0.6, rwidth=0.9,)
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.35)
plt.xlabel('time [s]')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The coordinates of each bin can be calculated like this:

```
midpoints = bins[:-1] + np.diff(bins)/2
coords = np.column_stack((midpoints,n))
coords = array([[ 0.31381516,  4.        ],
       [ 0.48719547,  0.        ],
       [ 0.66057579,  6.        ],
       [ 0.83395611, 12.        ],
       [ 1.00733642, 18.        ],
       [ 1.18071674,  6.        ],
       [ 1.35409705,  1.        ],
       [ 1.52747737,  0.        ],
       [ 1.70085768,  1.        ],
       [ 1.874238  ,  1.        ],
       [ 2.04761832,  1.        ],
       [ 2.22099863,  1.        ],
       [ 2.39437895,  0.        ],
       [ 2.56775926,  1.        ],
       [ 2.74113958,  1.        ],
       [ 2.91451989,  0.        ],
       [ 3.08790021,  0.        ],
       [ 3.26128053,  0.        ],
       [ 3.43466084,  1.        ]])
```

I would like to use `coords` to

- compute all the straight lines with negative slope
- get the one that has the minimum y=0 value
- plot that lines on the histogram and
- get the x-axis value of y=0 of that line

For example, in the histogram above, the solution should be like this:

[image]

which has a `y=0` value at `x= 0.48`. I would like to plot the line of the solution and get the value of `x` of that line when `y=0`.

In other histograms, the solutions are:

[image]

**EDIT**

Another dataset example to test solutions:

```
i3s1=[1.4856339999999992, 0.27564800000000034, 1.1008430000000011, 1.2301969999999987, 0.2667920000000006, 0.8187089999999984, 0.42119200000000134, 0.5471469999999989, 1.0582640000000012, 0.7725049999999989, 0.8486200000000004, 0.8414530000000013, 0.34434200000000104, 3.3969810000000003, 4.355844999999999, 1.5555109999999992, 1.2929899999999996, 1.2005979999999994, 2.6386439999999993, 1.2733500000000006, 1.2238090000000028, 1.406841, 1.227254000000002, 1.4577429999999936, 1.204816000000001, 0.4409120000000044, 1.1166549999999944, 0.20276700000000147, 3.8218770000000006, 0.11855700000000269, 2.541343999999995, 0.0911790000000039, 2.0708699999999993, 2.6000489999999985, 0.11452600000000501, 0.16021299999999883, 2.288936999999997, 0.266489, 0.18775300000000072, 2.497996999999998, 0.42036200000000434, 2.3378999999999976, 0.23202399999999557, 2.6313650000000024, 0.20198899999999753, 0.17698099999999783]
```

Comment: I have fixed the solution of the first example. The line should cross x-Axis at x=0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to get a list of all possible red lines and then find the [linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function_(calculus)) with a negative slope that has the smallest `x` value for `y=0`.

```python
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

#get all possible combinations of points that a linear function should cross
all_combinations = pd.DataFrame(
        map(lambda r: (r[0][0], r[0][1], r[1][0], r[1][1]), 
            combinations(coords,2)),
    columns=["x1", "y1", "x2", "y2"])

#calculate a and b for each linear function using y=a*x+b
all_combinations["a"] = ((all_combinations["y2"] - all_combinations["y1"]) 
    / (all_combinations["x2"] - all_combinations["x1"]))
all_combinations["b"] = (all_combinations["y2"] - 
    all_combinations["a"] * all_combinations["x2"])

#for each linear function get the x value for y=0 (called x0)
all_combinations["x0"] = - all_combinations["b"] / all_combinations["a"]

#only keep the functions with a negative slope
neg_slope = all_combinations[(all_combinations["a"] < 0) & 
    (all_combinations["a"] != float("inf")) 
    & (all_combinations["a"] != float("-inf"))]

#only keep the function with the smallest x0
miny0 = neg_slope[neg_slope["x0"] == neg_slope["x0"].min()].reset_index()
x1, y1, x0 = miny0["x1"][0],miny0["y1"][0],miny0["x0"][0]

#plot the result
plt.bar(x=coords[:,0], height=coords[:,1],width=0.1)
plt.plot([x1, x0], [y1, 0], color="red")
```

[image: negative_slope]

Comment: I am trying to run the code but there is an error with 'miny0' not defined.

Comment: you are right. I forgot to copy one line of code. I have added it now: `miny0 = neg_slope[ne...`

Comment: thank you, it seems to give an error with different data after testing it with i3s1 histogram data (I have edited in the text of the question above).

Comment: @user1993416 there was a problem with the index of the dataframe. Adding a `reset_index()` will (hopefully) solve the issue. I have added it in the code